# Custom ActionScript 3 Play/Pause button on raw animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I tried to search it on google but no one was matched to my search.
Anyway, I'd like to create a custom play / pause button for the animation to control the animation and the audio. I am not so familiar with ActionScript 3 so beg for me.

Here's my screenshot so you can see what i mean.
[image]

Thanks and looking forward.

Comment: Look for "Code snippets" panel in Flash IDE. There you can find prepared code for most common actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a layer with one keyframe at the begin, and normal frame till the end of your animation.

In this keyframe, you'll put the button for play/pause control.

On the document class (or *sigh* on the keyframe itself) you'll put something like that.

```
myPlayPauseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Click, playPauseHandler);

function playPauseHandler(e:Event):void{
    if(e.target.currentFrame == 1)  // button is in the play state 
        this.stop();
    else
        this.play();
}
```

please note that the "this" reference in the handler function, is referring to the main scene (the _root for the as2 programmers).

Note also that you can access this.currentFrame in order to know the current frame of the main animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
myPlayPauseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Click, playPauseHandler);
```

the Correct

```
myPlayPauseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playPauseHandler);
```